# SonarQube maven issue

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have installed a sonarqube on my server, and trying to run a 
mvn sonar:sonar on my project, but still receiving :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project weather-station: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project weather-station: null
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:80)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.download(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:103)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.loadPlugins(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:80)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.installRemotes(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:70)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginRepository.start(ScannerPluginRepository.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:100)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:89)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:220)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:59)
        ... 23 more
```

I can see that credentials from my settings.xml file in maven are correct (different output while changing them to incorrect ones) but this stack is no much of an info for me

Edit:
The sonarqube version is 6.5.0.27846 also the files seems to be loaded by maven, but then the problem occurs

```
[INFO] 19:22:59.921 Load plugins index
[DEBUG] 19:22:59.975 GET 200 http://MYMAGICDOMAIN/sonar/deploy/plugins/index.txt | time=53ms
[INFO] 19:23:00.001 Load plugins index (done) | time=80ms
[DEBUG] 19:23:00.002 Load plugins
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.474 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-05T19:23:00+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 61M/270M
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know your SonarQube version. But most of the time this issue is caused by a proxy that is messing up the response of HTTP call to `/deploy/plugins/index.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Could you re-run with -X and see if there is more light you can shed.

Comment: this is the stack visible with the -X option on ;), or do you mean some previous logs? to be correct, i am using "mvn sonar:sonar -X"

Answer (score 0):

This was somehow caused by apache2 proxy. Not sure how this happened, because the interface via browser was working perfectly. But just like @Julien H. mentioned, in case of this error it is good to double check your proxy settings ( and context values in sonar.properties )